# Ground transportation options for late arrival at Portland Oregon Airport (PDX)

Tags: transportation, airport-transfer, car-rentals, taxis, pdx

I have a flight arriving at 30 minutes past midnight at the Portland Oregon Airport (PDX). If possible, I would like to travel the same night from the airport to Hillsboro (about 30 miles away). There are many [ground transportation options](http://www2.portofportland.com/(X(1)S(s2ff3waatnvrbuviudemjwdg))/PDX/GroundTransportation) at the airport, but I'm having trouble finding any that are open all night.

I would prefer renting a car, but the car rental counters seem to close around 1:30a or 2:00a and I don't want to get stuck without transportation if the flight is delayed. Is there 24 hour car rental at PDX? Does anyone know if the car rental companies will stay open for delayed flights? Are there other shuttle services or taxis operating 24 hours?

Answer (score 6):

After some calling around, I confirmed that the rental car companies Avis, Dollar and Thrifty at PDX are open 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Most US car-rental companies ask for your flight number when you reserve a car, and if that flight is delayed, they will know it. The chances that your domestic flight will arrive over an hour late are quite small, and I think if you are reassured by the car rental agency that they won't close up if you are delayed, you'll be fine. I think also many airports have curfews that make arriving between 2 and 6 unlikely - if your flight into PDX is delayed too much, it won't even leave and you'll be arriving in the morning. I wouldn't hesitate to book a car under the circumstances you have here. But do book it - don't arrive without a reservation.